# What does Firebase Auth library do to require all the setup?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

To login a user using Firebase REST API, all I have to do is POST to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=APIKEY`.
That's it.

To do the exact same thing using [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start), I have to install command-line tools, run  scripts that add platform-specific dependencies, download config files from Firebase, generate sources and god knows what. I mean just look at [this setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android), and all that is before I even get to do *anything* auth-related  Like... what the heck? What is this thing doing under the hood to require this much theater? Why would I ever prefer this to a simple HTTP call? Sure, I get auto token-refreshing (right?), but that's just another simple HTTP call anyway.

Also, if I just do this:

```
Firebase.initializeApp(options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: '...',
      appId: '...',
      messagingSenderId: '...',
      projectId: '...'));
```

I seem to be able to side-step the entire crazy setup just fine. No new dependencies, no nothing. So again... what am I missing here?

Comment: You missing that you no need a heck of lot more parameters. Just pass those you need.

Comment: It’s the difference between a simple call to a REST API and the use of a full SDK. Maybe the gain of using the SDK is not crystal clear with the Auth service and simple methods like signIn but with Firestore or Cloud Storage you’ll very rapidly understand why it’s much much easier to use the SDK.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Ok, point taken, but... that doesn't explain why wouldn't I just provide `FirebaseOptions` myself, like in the 2nd part of the question. No tools needed, no dependencies...